# How to solve "ax⁴ + bx² + c = 0" in Python?

Tags: python, function, math, input

How do you solve ax⁴ + bx² + c = 0, when a, b, c are inputs from the user?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but what does “ if x1 != x2 != x3 != x4:” mean?

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: How do you solve this equation in python? And by that I test if the there are four different zeropoints or 3 and so on.

Comment: Use a root finding algorithm like Newton's or secant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve ax⁴ + bx³ + cx² + dx + e = 0, you could use numpy to do so.  For example, for the equation 2x⁴ - x² = 0, it would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
a, b, c, d, e = 2, 0, -1, 0, 0
coeff = [a, b, c, d, e]
print( np.roots(coeff) )
```

yielding `[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678  0.          0.        ]` as the solution.

Accepting user input would require other steps to have the user enter values and parsing those values. This could be accomplished by using the `input()` function or arguments with a python script.

Comment: I think this is wrong, because now I have a solution and the values from your solution are not nearly the same. I can also tell that my solutions is right, by typing the function at "geogebra.org/classic" and reading the zeropoints off.                                                        
The output is the follwing:                                                                              
(function is 2x⁴ - x²)                                                   
my solution: [-0.707106781186548, 0, 0.707106781186548];  
your solution: [0.5 0. ]

Comment: Yep, I missed a coefficient. Corrected.